# Why does int main() {} compile?

Tags: c++, return-value, program-entry-point

(I'm using Visual C++ 2008) I've always heard that main() is *required* to return an integer, but here I didn't put in `return 0;` and and it compiled with 0 errors and 0 warnings!  In the debug window it says the program has exited with code 0.  If this function is named anything other than main(), the compiler complains saying 'blah' must return a value.  Sticking a `return;` also causes the error to appear.  But leaving it out completely, it compiles just fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hey look I'm supposed to return an int but I'm not gonna!\n";
}
```

Could this be a bug in VC++?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> ## 3.6.1 Main function
>
> ....
>
> 2 An implementation shall not predefine the `main` function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of main:
>
> ```
> int main() { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
> /* ... */
> }
> ```
>
> .... and it continues to add ...
>
> 5 A `return` statement in `main` has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling `exit` with the return value as the argument. **If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0**;

attempting to find an online copy of the C++ standard so I could quote this passage [I found a blog post that quotes all the right bits better than I could.](http://zamanbakshifirst.blogspot.com/2006/11/c-c-main-should-return-void.html)

Comment: g++ will throw an error at you by default for doing this.  most other compilers do "return 0" instead

Comment: Older versions of GCC actually returned garbage in some instances if you didn't have a return statement in main().

Comment: @wakingrufus, what version of g++ are you using?  I'm getting the correct behavior as described by sparkes.

Comment: Note that the standard quoted is C99, not C89 or C++98, yet MSVC mostly implements C89 and not C99 or C11 when used as a C compiler.  However, you can also consult the Microsoft documentation — which is where `void main(…)` is defined as OK (in C).

Answer (score 18):

This is part of the C++ language standard. An implicit return 0 is generated for you if there's no explicit return statement in main.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure VC++ just inserts a return 0 if you don't include one in main functions. The same thing can happen with functions too, but in those cases at least you'll get a warning.

Comment: It is undefined behavior to fall off the end of a non-void function.  Only main is special with implicit return.

Answer (score 2):

Section 6.6.3/2 states- "Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.".

An example is the code below which at best gives warning on VS 2010/g++

```
int f(){
   if(0){
      if(1)
         return true;
   }
}

int main(){
   f();
}
```

So the whole point is that 'main' is special as the previous responses have pointed out.