# Comparing Integers C++

Tags: c++

Hey So I am learning basic c++ just started this week, I have a question that says:

Write a program to compare 3 integers and print the largest, the program should ONLY Use 2 IF statements.

I am not sure how to do this so any help would be appreciated

So far I have this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
int a, b, c;

cout << "Please enter three integers: ";
cin >> a >> b >> c;

if ( a > b && a > c) 
    cout << a;
else if ( b > c && b > a)
    cout << b;
else if (c > a && c > b)
    cout << b;

system("PAUSE");

}
```

Comment: This is more about logic than about comparing stuff in `C++`. Either way, I don't think SO is the place to ask.

Comment: nvm I see the answer bellow

Answer (score 6):

```
int main()
{
  int a, b, c;
  cout << "Please enter three integers: ";
  cin >> a >> b >> c;
  int big_int = a;

  if (a < b)
  {
      big_int = b;
  }

  if (big_int < c)
  {
    big_int = c;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also note, you should write `int main()` instead of `void main()`.

Comment: thanks for the info on int main()

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    std::cout << "Please enter three integers: ";
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;

    int max = a;
    if (max < b)
        max = b;
    if (max < c)
        max = c;

    std::cout << max;    
}
```

Although the above code satisfies the exercise question, I thought I'll add a couple of other ways to show ways of doing it without any `if`s.

Doing it in a more cryptic, unreadable way, which is discouraged, would be

```
int max = (a < b) ? ((b < c)? c : b) : ((a < c)? c : a);
```

An elegant way would be to `#include <algorithm>` and

```
int max = std::max(std::max(a, b), c);
```

With C++11, you can even do

```
const int max = std::max({a, b, c});
```

Comment: There should probably be a `return` at the end.

Comment: In C++ (not C) the return statement when omitted in main function (and only in main function), a default of 0 is returned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239/why-does-int-main-compile

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the last "else if" statement. In this part of code it is sure that "c" is maximal - no number is larger.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: one of your `if` statements is useless (actually, it introduces a bug because nothing will be printed if a, b and c are all equal).