# (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main' When trying to Compile .cpp file

Tags: c++

when trying to compile a .cpp file called rat with a .h file called normalize which is located in a different folder (rat.h is in the same folder as rat.cpp) , I'm typing

```
g++ -I/opt/cis/include/ -I/opt/cis/lib/ rat.cpp
```

I have included an int main () in the .cpp file itself, and have completely commented out the inner workings of the .h file and the .cpp file just to try to compile correctly.

The .h file (commented items not included)

```
  1 #ifndef RAT_H
  2 #define RAT_H
  3 #include <iostream>
  4 #include <string>
  5 
  6 class Rat {
  7         friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Rat &);
  8         friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Rat &);
  9         private:
 10                 double n,d;
 11         public: 
 12                 Rat(): n(0), d(1) {}
 13 };
 14. #endif
```

The .cpp file

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <cstdlib>
  3 #include <string>
  4 #include <sstream>
  5 #include "rat.h"
  6 #include "normalize.h"
  7 using namespace std;
  8 #ifdef TEST_RAT
  9 int main() {};
  10 #endif
```

What am I doing incorrectly?  Sorry if it is obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Your `main` function exists only if the macro `TEST_RAT` is defined. Either:

- add `-DTEST_RAT` to your compiler CFLAGS
- add the line `#define TEST_RAT` *before* the `#ifdef`
- remove the `#ifdef TEST_RAT` and `#endif` pair in your .cpp

Comment: There are two allowed signatures of main: `int main()` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: It is allowed, but is not the standard.

Comment: I'm not fully sure, but I think it's standart too. GCC with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` don't complain about it.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. What is against the standard is `void main`

Comment: [`int main()` is standard.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239/why-does-int-main-compile/22262#22262)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot :

```
#define TEST_RAT
```

This is not defined in your code so this should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you put your `main()` in an `#ifdef` it is left out if `TEST_RAT` is not defined. Since it isn't you don't have a `main` so you cannot create an executable (there is no point of entry) and `g++` fails with the error seen.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you wanted to put this in your main (to make sure the Rat class is defined):

```
    #ifdef RAT_H
    int main() {};
    #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, since no-one's mentioned it yet, is the `-c` flag:

```
g++ -c -I/opt/cis/include/ -I/opt/cis/lib/ rat.cpp
```

This will compile rat.cpp to an object file rat.o without attempting to link it into a program (and so require a `main`).

If you're testing for correctness you might also want to try `-W` or `-Wall` for warnings.

Comment: -c compiles and outputs the file to an object file. If you want only to test if it compiles, you may also add the `-o /dev/null` option